# Invalid column name error with EF 4.1 Code First

Tags: foreign-keys, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I've been having a problem with this for about a day now, I've searched and found similar problems with their solutions but haven't been able to fix this.

I've seen this done with the Teams example, so I'll do the same. I have a `Team`:

```
public abstract class Team
{
   [Key]
   public int IdTeam { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a `Match` object:

```
public class Match
{
   [Key]
   public int IdMatch { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("HomeTeam")]
   public int IdHomeTeam { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("AwayTeam")]
   public int IdAwayTeam { get; set; }

   public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
   public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever I try to access the name of either team I get an `Invalid column name Team_TeamId` error. I'm guessing it has something to do with EF and the Foreign Keys not being mapped correctly. I've also seen other people use ICollections, but I don't think I need them for this case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix this in the `OnModelCreating` method. Entity framework can't seem to recognize the foreign keys, so you have to specify it specifically.

```
public class Entities : DbContext
{
    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
            .HasRequired(b => b.AwayTeam)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.IdAwayTeam);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
            .HasRequired(b => b.HomeTeam)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.IdHomeTeam);
    }
}
```

*for more information about code first `OnModelCreating` check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.103).aspx*

Comment: why is team abstract btw? Does Team have a collection of matches?

Comment: No, it does not have a collection. No collection, no abstract?

Comment: this should work, try it. Entity framework can't handle this standard, we explicitily tell it.

Comment: This should actually be the solution to your problem, could you try to change the foreign keys back. Does it also happen if you (temporary) remove one of the foreign keys?